# Need help enabling USB on an HP Proliant DL385p gen8

Tags: hp-proliant, usb

Over the course of troubleshooting remote mounting issues, I disabled all USB in the RBSU. I wasn't paying attention or didn't see the warning that this would disable input through iLO.

So I sent the datacenter tech to turn it back on in the bios. Only ... keyboards are USB these days...

So I'm wondering is my only course of action to reset the server to factory defaults? (Not that big of a deal as it wasn't in service yet, just have to re-IP iLO)

I'd like to not have to do that, but at this point, I think that's my only option.

TL;DR Did a dumb move, locked self out of input into the server, looking for a non-reset solution if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

SSH to the ILO and use the `textcons` command to bring up a text-based console.

You'll be able to get into the BIOS this way and reenable your USB settings. Press `F9` when the system posts.

Use `ESC+SHIFT+(` to exit the remote console session.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a really cool trick!  I'll definitely remember that.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to help because I get this:  "Monitor is in graphics mode or an unsupported text mode." Once it gets past post.

Comment: You have to watch carefully and press F9 when the text screen comes back. (It's when the server beeps twice)

Comment: You mean when it comes back from that message?  (Which it does eventually)

Comment: I think it's not taking it because of the lack of USB support.  I spammed F9 until finally after a while after that message it goes from black to brown and starts trying to boot from CD-ROM and others.

Comment: Using integrated remote console, I was able to determine that the time that it is giving that message is when you would normally get the black proliant screen.  So the F9 isn't doing anything :(

Answer (score 0):

another option is to enable the override jumper on the motherboard.

enable position 1 and position 6
then turn the server on

let it sit there in a reboot cycle anywhere from 10 to 30 minutes
then turn jumpers back to default and reboot.

Bios settings will be defaulted.  USB Keyboards will work

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while configuring HP Proliant G9.
Here is how I solved it:

1. Downloaded the ILO remote console
2. Logged in from this console to ILO using default IPv6 address (it was showing during boot process) and default username and password (found it on the label on the top of the server).
3. Using ILO remote console got to BIOS screen and enabled USB.